# How would I have string validate just the ENTER key being hit?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

```
void Game::validate(string& str1)
{
    bool exit = false;
    int strLength = str1.length();
    while (exit == false)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++)
        {
            if(!isalpha(str1[i]) || isspace(str1[i])) //|| str1.empty())//?
            {
                cout << "Not a valid name, please try again: " << endl;
                getline(cin, str1);
            }
            else if(isalpha(str1[i]))
            {
                exit = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

> I am passing down a string,i need to output the error message
>   if the user hits the Enter key only*. Ive tried using '\n' but isspace should take care of that(which it dosent). When i run the program and hit ENTER only, it freezes...whats wrong with it??? All other validation works except the ENTER key
>
> Blockquote

Comment: How do you read the string? `getline` won't append a newline character.

Comment: A function called `validate` shouldn't be prompting for input

Comment: yes I am using getline..

Comment: so cin >> ? I thought cin ignores white space

Comment: Well then it's an empty string. So you have: exit == false, so the while loop runs. i < strLength is false, so the for loop doesn't. exit==false is true, so the while loop runs again, and so on.

Comment: Wouldn't replacing `isspace(str1[i])` with `str1.empty()` work?

Comment: @JamesRoot they are similar, but replacing it still dosent solve the enter key problem

Answer (score 0):

try and print out your string before you start checking and you'll probably
see that the string is not empty even though enter key was the only input.
before you have the user input try and flush the stream.
try `std::cout<<endl;`

Comment: tried it, but still wont work. The string is definitely not empty, and I understand what your saying. Im going to try other flush methods.